# Merge different schema from blob container into a single sql table

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I have to read 10 files from a folder in blob container with different schema(most of the schema among the table macthes) and merge them into a single SQL table
file 1: lets say there are 25 such columns

[image]

file 2: Some of the column in file2 matches with columns in file1

[image]

file 3:

[image]

output: a sql table

[image]

How to setup a pipeline in azure data factory to merge these columns into a single SQL table.

### my approach:
get Metadata Activity---> for each childitems--- copy activity

for the mapping--- i constructed a json that containes all the source/sink columns from these files

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSON file which contains your each source file name and Tabular Translator. Then use Lookup activity to get this file's content(Don't check first row only). Loop this array in For Each activity and pass source file name in your dataset. Finally, create a copy data activity and use Tabular Translator as your mapping.